# PHP not able to execute program, though permission available to www-data

Tags: php, apache, executable, file-permissions

I have a PHP-code which is as follows:-

```
<html>
<?php
$output = shell_exec("/home/ak/Documents/Translation/mosesdecoder/bin/moses"); 
echo $output;
?>
</html>
```

When, I execute this PHP file through browser, no output appears on the browser window. However, I have done `chmod -R 775 /home/ak/Documents/Translation/` and thus I know that `moses` can be executed by everyone.

Further to confirm that the user `www-data` (the web user) has permissions to execute `moses`, I executed `moses` in the my Ubuntu terminal using

`sudo -u www-data /home/ak/Documents/Translation/mosesdecoder/bin/moses`

and an output, describing how to use the program `moses`, appeared on the terminal.

Why is the same output not appearing on the browser, when `www-data` has the permission?

Thakns in advance.

Comment: Could `moses` be writing to stderr instead of stdout?

Comment: did you confirm if shell_exec is not disabled in your php.ini. ?

Comment: @Siguza...yes, that was the problem...thanks...I had to use proc_open() to read the output from std_err